# How to run multiple webbrowsers each simultaneously performing their own automated tasks with mouse cursors specifically?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, cursor, mouse

So far I have used python, selenium and pyautogui, and I want to run lots of webbrowsers performing their own tasks with mouse cursors on various websites to simulate normal human use of websites. In Windows OS it is also possible to have, as far as I know, only one mouse cursor.

I don't know how to either create these separate environments running in the background with each having their own mouse cursor - or I don't know and cannot find any other approach to achieve that.
In the screenshot below I'm sending a fragment of a youtube video on which someone has achieved smth like that and I propably might need smth quite the same. How to do that?
[image]

Comment: Selenium doesn't use the cursors.  I say cursors because Mouse/keyboard (usually called caret?) each control their own.  Selenium generates the events that a cursor would generate.  Robot-like frameworks like pyautogui can work with cursors because they are running at the OS level... not in the browser per say, but since humans have two arms, there's only two cursors per OS.  You can run Selenium multi-threaded with each thread having a browser/driver pair.  That's enough to simulate user actions.  This person may have robot-like frameworks running in different docker containers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using virtual machines to achieve this as each virtual machine will be independent and that way you can deploy as needed. although this can be resource intensive so i would recommend allocating only the resources needed. to save time you can create one virtual machine and then duplicate it. you can use a manager to swap between the different machines otherwise paid software would be the easiest and cleanest way to achieve that goal.

Comment: I am now again looking for virtual machine software/solutions for this. The problem is, I would need to sometimes simulatenously run a lot of webbrowsers, and if this meant running a lot of virtual machines, then I don't know if that's even possible as this might, I assume, take a lot of resources..
Because I have not received any fully satisfying answers about all that yet, I will just test myself how this could work with virtual machines, if at all

Comment: Try setting up the VMs and seeing how resource heaving it is an if its too heavy consider using cloud computing for some additional power or us a cloud VMs might be easier and there are free ones out there.